# Array Items other than 1st item is not set on edittext

Tags: android, arrays, android-edittext, items

I have a java class function as shown below

```
void Populate8(String sv1)
{
String[] data = sv1.split(":");
String name = data[1];
String bnumber = data[2];
String nos = data[6];
String pps = data[7];
EditText fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
EditText busnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
EditText numberofseats = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
EditText priceperseat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
fullname.setText(name);
busnumber.setText(bnumber);
numberofseats.setText(nos);
priceperseat.setText(pps);
}
```

when it send following string;. It only shows value in first text field. not on others.

```
populate8("1:Hello:BTX-2233:Makkah:Madinah:7 AM:35:30");
```

but it shows only "Hello" in first edittext field. It donot adds "BTX-2233" in other field and on rest of the two fields. What is the problem?

Here is the layout design of my android studio app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bdatarlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:text="@string/userid" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="10sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
android:text="@string/busnum" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText5"
android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
android:text="@string/from" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="10sp" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:textSize="10sp" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/spinner5"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/to" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner6"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/spinner6"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/time" />

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner7"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView12"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/spinner7"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/numberofseat" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView13"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText9"
android:layout_marginStart="-44dp"
android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
android:text="@string/pps" />

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText10"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText9"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/bdback"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
android:text="@string/back" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bdback"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:text="@string/aud" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView14"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="-91dp"
android:text="@string/dnam" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btngetdriverdata"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView14"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:text="@string/fetchdata" />

<WebView
android:id="@+id/webservicebdd"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="46dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/locpb9

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

from EditTexts `editText5`, `editText9` and `editText10`.
With this attribute you restrict the values entered to the EditTexts only to alphabetical characters.